# How to add velocity to drag and drop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, physics

So for my game I want to be able to pick up objects with my cursor and fling them. I got the drag and drop working on my own but I don't know how to make it fling the object if you  throw it. If you try to fling it, the object just drops to the floor. Can someone help me? I tried looking online but I couldn't find a solution. Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DragAndDropObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canDrag = true;
    public bool isDragging;
    GameObject player;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(canDrag && player.GetComponent<Movement>().draggingEnabled)
        {
            if(!isDragging)
            {
                print("start dragging");
                isDragging = true;
                rb.gravityScale = 0f;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
                player.GetComponent<Movement>().draggingObject = true;

                GameObject[] heavyObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Heavy");

                foreach (GameObject heavy in heavyObjects)
                {
                    heavy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if(isDragging)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            rb.gravityScale = 1f;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
            player.GetComponent<Movement>().draggingObject = false;
            print("stop dragging");

            GameObject[] heavyObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Heavy");

            foreach (GameObject heavy in heavyObjects)
            {
                heavy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        if(isDragging)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePos, 1f);

            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f )
            {
                gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10f);
            }
            else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f )
            {
                gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, -10f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have the answer please tell me! Thank you!

Comment: Also this is in unity 2d

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be to get the object velocity using [RigidBody2D.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) and add it to the object transform. You might also multiply the velocity by [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to make the flying process smoother.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).